# String to Table in Lua

Tags: lua

I am using LuaSocket and http.request to call a remote PHP script that generates a Lua table and outputs it to the browser.

When I store the http.request response in a variable it's a string, which renders the table unusable in my Lua code.

For example:

```
eventData = http.request("http://www.example.com/events.php")
print( eventData )

--print outputs this "string", that is really a Lua table that PHP generated
months={
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
}
```

If I try calling months[4], for example, it errors out with "attempt to index global 'months' (a nil value)".
How can I cast that string as a usable table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [loadstring](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) to create a lua chunk that you can execute.

```
eventData = [[
months = {
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December',
}
]]

loadstring(eventData)()
if months then
    print(table.concat(months, ", "))
end
```

Comment: Technically, you should use `assert(loadstring(eventData))()` to propagate any syntax errors in the provided code (as opposed to just popping an unexplained "attempt to call a nil value" error).

Comment: I see a serious security problem here, json and a suitable parser or similar method for lua-like syntax would be the right way to go.

Answer (score 4):

As of Lua 5.2, load supports strings as arguments.  So you can now use Adam's answer above replacing loadstring with load.

Note that `load(eventData)` creates a chunk of type "function" and `load(eventData)()` creates a chunk and calls it—thereby creating your table.  This had me tripped up for a little while.