# How can I convert a table-formatted string into a table without using load() or loadstring()?

Tags: string, lua, lua-table

Another question ([String to Table in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518903/string-to-table-in-lua)) has asked how to convert a string that is formatted as a table into a string, and the given answer was to use `loadstring` or `load` to convert the string into a chunk that is then executed.

I also have a program that downloads a file that is formatted like a lua table using `http.request` just like the other question:

```
yourTable = http.request("http://www.somesite.com/table.txt")
print(yourTable)

--yourTable is a string that is formatted like a lua table, but not a table:
a={
    b = {
      c = 1,
      d = {
        e = {
        },
      },
    },
}

functionThatExpectsATable(yourTable) --throws error because yourTable is a string
```

While I could use `load` or `loadstring` to get the table I want, that is a potential security vulnerability because my program, by design, allows the user to input any URL to load their table data from. If they pointed to lua code instead of a lua-formatted table, that code would be executed.

How can I convert the "table-formatted string" into a table without executing it?

Comment: Short of writing your own parser, I don't think you can. It's less trouble to just run whatever script in a sandbox and then verify the result doesn't contain anything you don't want (such as functions).

Comment: there is https://bitbucket.org/alexames/lon never tried it out though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample implementation from the [Penlight](https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight) library:

https://github.com/stevedonovan/Penlight/blob/master/lua/pl/pretty.lua

See the `pretty.read` function

Comment: Thanks. I knew _someone_ must have had a need to do this securely.

Comment: Be careful, `pretty.read` would fail on two consecutive hyphens inside strings: `pretty.read('-- table of players\n {{nickname="--=Eagle=--", score=0}}')`